# android- Listener lost when screen orientation changes

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a `ListFragment` which opens an `Activity` when it is clicked. Now, my problem is that my listener is lost when the screen is rotated. The click events does not respond. I have tried `android:configChanges` , it fixes the listener problem but the layout of the  whole activity looks weird. Any possible solutions to set listener again on configuration change?

Comment: Can you post some code to describe your problem better?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution: The better way to handle the problem by using onSaveInstanceState().see this link  [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

No.2: You can detect the change and then handle it through the below method:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(config);

// Checks the orientation
if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

The forced solution: if you don't want to recycle the activity lifecycle on orientation change then you can add this in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

The last one is the worst solution, but works. 
As my suggestion never use the last one because you can't able to do any kind of recycle things in future. but for emergency solution its good.